# Where ampersand "&" can be put when passing argument by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, declaration

In the examples that I saw the arguments were passed by reference in the following way:

```
void AddOne(int &y)
```

In the code that I have I see the following syntax:

```
void AddOne(int& y)
```

I wonder if it is the same or the second case is somehow different from the first one.

Comment: Whitespace in C++ doesn't matter. You could do `void AddOne(int                     &          y)` if you wanted to.

Comment: @chris: That isn't exactly true.  `unsignedint` and `unsigned int` are different sequences of tokens.  But the code shown in this question doesn't differ in the tokens.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the second option is clearer; `int&` is the type of `y`.

Comment: @JSQuareD: I prefer `int &y` (when I think more), especially if you declare more than one variable on the same line. I mean if I write `int& y=i, x=i`. Is `x` a reference here? Seems confusing? But `int &y=i, x=i` is a bit better, I think.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I was thinking about that. I couldn't come up with a good wording for it. It *usually* doesn't matter, but when it does, it seems more like common sense. If both of these work, it makes sense that the spacing makes no difference.

Comment: @Nawaz That's why I always avoid to declare multiple pointers or references on the same line. ;) But yeah, that certainly is something to watch out for.

Comment: @JSQuareD - `int& y, z;` `int&` is the type of `y`, but not of `z`.

Comment: @JSQuareD: What if I write and you read? :P

Comment: @JSQuareD: As far type of a variable is concerned, (C and ) C++ is very confusing in that regard. In the declaration `int x[10]`, the type of `x` is `int[10]` but it is not written as `int[10] x`.

Comment: @Nawaz Yup, that's my biggest pet peeve in C++. Arrays, pointers and references are, in my opinion, completely distinct data types from their 'base'. This is also reflected in the syntax of newer languages such as Java and C#. To avoid confusion, I almost never write multiple pointers and/or references on the same line, or arrays on the same line as their 'base'.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Both are *exactly* the same. No difference at all.

All that matters is that `&` should be between the *type* and the *variable* name. Spaces don't matter.

So

```
void AddOne(int&  y);
void AddOne(int  &y);
void AddOne(int & y)
void AddOne(int   &     y);
void AddOne(int&y);
```

are same!

Comment: as well as `int&y` (no spaces).

Comment: This really confuses me, doesn't the code formatter take care of it, so all the `&  *` follows the C++ standard formatting.

Comment: @HarounHajem: Of course, a code formatter can take care of these, but IF `int&  y` and `int &y`, for example, are not semantically identical, then the code formatter is _not_ allowed to format one form into another, as that will be bug. Only if these different forms are identical, the code formatter can format them to the _preferred_ form. Hope that helps you and now it's not confusing anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same for the language, just different code conventions

Answer (score 1):

There is no differences between

```
void AddOne(int &y);
```

and

```
void AddOne(int& y);
```

and even

```
void AddOne(int&y);
```

in C++, as the whitespaces between actual tokens are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of style. Both are correct and valid.

However it seems Bjarne Stroustrup prefers putting the `&` and  `*` beside the type name, emphasising the type of the variable:

```cpp
int* i;   // i is a pointer to an int 
int& j;   // j is a reference to an int
```

See here for the pointers: https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace

See examples in "Programming Principles and Practices using C++" book and here for references: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/11/c-creator-bjarne-stroustrup-answers-our-top-five-c-questions/

Comment: and here a related question regarding pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994573/c-style-stroustrup-s-placement-of-pointer-asterisks

Comment: and another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766907/whats-the-semantically-accurate-position-for-the-ampersand-in-c-references