# What's the semantically accurate position for the ampersand in C++ references

Tags: c++, reference

It's pretty common knowledge that the semantically accurate way to declare pointers is

```
int *x;
```

instead of

```
int* x;
```

This is because C sees `*x` as an int, not `x` as an int pointer.

This can be easily demonstrated by

```
int* a, b;
```

where `a` is an int pointer, while `b` is an int.

There are at least 5 duplicate questions on Stack Overflow that discuss this issue for pointers. But what about references?

Comment: Downvoters, mind explaining? Is it considered bad style to post questions that you already have the answers for? Isn't that what that button is there for?

Comment: Spaces don't matter, as they are skipped during the lexing phase.  You can have zero or more space before and zero or more spaces after the asterisk.  **They both declare x as a pointer, not a reference.**

Comment: @mic_e: That's *exactly* what that button is there for. We even have a post on meta demonstrating it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz Unfortunately this is often seen as an attempt to gain more rep, even though answering your own question is certainly encouraged.

Comment: Both are "semantically correct", since white-space has no semantic meaning. If you like consistency, then make your reference declarations match your pointer declarations. If you don't, then do whatever you feel like.

Comment: I see. Probably, 'sematically correct' was a bad term to use, then... what I'm talking about is the syntax that most closely resembles the semantic meaning. If you know a better term for that, feel free to edit/suggest.

Comment: In C++ it is considered good style to put the pointer (*), reference (&) or other type modifiers together with the type and not right before the name. This is because `int& i` separates names and types better than `int &i`. See the articles on isocpp.org, Herb Sutters or scott Meyers for examples.

Comment: @Jens: It's pretty horrible, if you think about it... C++ follows a completely different design philosophy than C, prompting `int& i` as good style, but due to its legacy C compatibility that 'good style' directly cloaks the actual semantics of your code...

Comment: I don't see were anything is cloaked. When I see the declaration `int const& x` I can read it easily from right to left as reference to a const int. What is cloaked? And in both languages, doing something like `int *i, j` in one line is considered bad style.

Comment: It definitely is bad style, but someone who has not done research into the problem will automatically assume that `int& a, b;` declares two references, and I think that is a serious problem, especially since the compiler might not even print a warning.

Comment: Handling multiple declarations in that way was a *very bad* design choice when creating the C language. Now, we are stuck with it, in C++ too. It's true that using `int *i` better matches that language-semantics rule, however, it's a terrible rule. The better way to deal with it is to (1) not allow multiple declarations and (2) distinguish the type from the identifier (e.g. `int* i` or `int& i`). Anyone with the least bit of knowledge in C/C++ knows about this rule, and so, we don't need to remind people of it, we just need to avoid it.

Comment: "This is because C sees *x as an int, not x as an int pointer." - rubbish. "This can be easily demonstrated by"  - no, you are just demonstrating how the comma works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While researching for this question, I already found the answer:

The `&` needs to be written just like the `*`.

The demonstration code is similar to the pointer demonstration code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;

    int& ar = a, br = b;

    br = 2;

    return b;
}
```

This returns 1, which means that `ar` is an int reference, while `br` is just an integer.

Comment: Many style guides suggest one variable per declaration.  Although more than one is possible, readability is improved when it comes to pointer and reference declaration.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Definitely. In no way I would encourage actually declaring multiple pointers, references or even variables in one statement. This is just a demonstration of the internal workings of `C++`.

Comment: As this code's result demonstrates, commas in C++ variable declarations have a nuanced meaning that is different from their meaning in other languages and isn't necessarily intuitively obvious. I agree that they should be avoided. However, I do prefer to place a space either before or both before and after an ampersand.

Answer (score 27):

Bjarne Stroustrup says:

> A `typical C programmer` writes `int *p`; and explains it `*p is what is the int` emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++) declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed, the * binds to the name p in the grammar.
>
> A `typical C++ programmer` writes `int* p;` and explains it `p is a pointer to an int` emphasizing type. Indeed the type of p is int*. I clearly prefer that emphasis and see it as important for using the more advanced parts of C++ well.

When declaring a pointer variable or argument, you may place the asterisk (or ampersand) adjacent to either the type or to the variable name.

The most important thing is to do this consistently within a single file.

```
// These are fine, space preceding.
char *c;
const int &i;

// These are fine, space following.
char* c;
const int& i;
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to "template typedefs", you can declare multiple references in an (arguably) nicer way:

```
template<typename T> using ref = T&;
int a, b;
ref<int> ar = a, br = b;
```