# C++ style: Stroustrup' s placement of pointer asterisks

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, conventions

Does anyone know why Stroustrup's style is the placement of pointers as follows?  Specifically, what Stroustrup has provided for guidance about this matter?

```
int* p;
```

vs

```
int *p;
```

because declaring multiple variables would require the asterisk next to each variable name.  Which would result in:

```
int* p, *x;
```

vs

```
int *p, *x;
```

In K&R C book, they explain that the asterisk/pointer is used as a mnemonic to aid in understanding.  I find it odd that the pointer/asterisk is tied to the type, vs the variable as the second of each example shows.  Interested if there is some background to why the first style is chosen.

Hoping for some quote from Stroustrup in the reasoning for this.

I'm adding in K&R C 2nd Edition grammar Page 235 where the asterisk (pointer) is tied to the declarator, which is an identifier.

[image: K&R p235 2nd Ed]

**ANSWER**
In this [article from Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) on coding style.  He explains that both are valid and it depends on programmer preference.

I disagree that this is an opinion based question.  Stroustrup's article clearly answers the question without opinion.

Comment: I only ever declare 1 variable at a time each on their own line. I also only name a variable a 1 letter name only in the case that it is a loop index ( or x, y and z) otherwise the name of a variable is usually way more descriptive. If you give your variables a good name you may not have to write a comment describing what the variable means.

Comment: In `K&R C` it was *compulsory* to declare all variables at the top of a function before any other code. This meant that multiple variable declarations were common. In `C++` that restriction was lifted and iit has always been recommended not to declare a variable until the point you need to use it. It has always, therefore, been considered bad style to declare your variables in batches before they are needed. Straustrup said he would have changed the multiple declaration syntax to be more "type-centric" if he did not need `C++` to remain backwards compatible with `C`.

Comment: @Galik I think if what you said is true then it makes sense.

Comment: @drescherjm I have had this question too, I agree the asterisk should be associated with the type, I understand what you are saying, but the only case I don't understand is when you are declaring multiple pointers as members of a class. You may not be initializing them there especially if you are working with an older C++ standard.

Comment: Use `int * p` style, so each camps would dislike ;-)

Comment: Wonder if it also applies to typedef `typedef int *intPtr;` vs `typedef int* intPtr;` (whereas `using intPtr = int*;`).

Comment: Note that this issue is moot in "modern" C++ (i.e. this decade). We now declare the pointer as `auto p = &i`.

Comment: Related, I just read a declaration/initialization like `int x, y = foo();` in a piece of C code, and having been writing Python for the last some time, went "wait what, how can you return two values from a C function??". Take care when declaring multiple variables on the same statement, it can be confusing to readers.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Note that we're talking about C++ here, not C. And in C++ we _can_ write `auto [x,y] = foo();`.

Comment: @MSalters, well, yes, though I'm pretty sure `int *a, b;` and `int x, y = foo();` work the same in C and C++, so it doesn't matter which one it was. The point is that both can be confusing for the reader and would be better on two lines. Or, if modern C++ has better features, so much the better! (I have to say, I like the qualifier "this decade", when were just less than five months in to 2020. :)

Comment: Maybe a better question is "why did the language creators define the grammar so that `b` is an `int` in `int * a, b` (any choice of spacing), if it clashes with the (now) common understanding that `int *` is a type and `a,b` are variable names".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

C++ emphasis heavily on *types* and when it comes to pointers declaration, to avoid any sort of confusion, Bjarne suggested - `Stick to one pointer per declaration`.

From [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) *[emphasis added]*:

> Is `int* p;` right or is `int *p;` right?
>
> Both are "right" in the sense that both are valid C and C++ and both have exactly the same meaning. As far as the language definitions and the compilers are concerned we could just as well say `int*p;` or `int * p;`
>
> The choice between `int* p;` and `int *p;` is not about right and wrong, but about style and emphasis. C emphasized expressions; declarations were often considered little more than a necessary evil. C++, on the other hand, has a heavy emphasis on types.
>
> A `typical C programmer` writes `int *p;` and explains it `*p is what is the int` emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++) declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed, the `*` binds to the name `p` in the grammar.
>
> A `typical C++ programmer` writes `int* p;` and explains it `p is a pointer to an int` emphasizing type. Indeed the type of `p` is `int*`. I clearly prefer that emphasis and see it as important for using the more advanced parts of C++ well.
>
> The critical confusion comes (only) when people try to declare several pointers with a single declaration:
>
> `int* p, p1;   // probable error: p1 is not an int*`
>
> Placing the `*` closer to the name does not make this kind of error significantly less likely.
>
> `int *p, p1;   // probable error?`
>
> Declaring one name per declaration minimizes the problem - in particular when we initialize the variables. People are far less likely to write:
>
> `int* p = &i;`
>      `int p1 = p;   // error: int initialized by int*`
>
> And if they do, the compiler will complain.
>   Whenever something can be done in two ways, someone will be confused. Whenever something is a matter of taste, discussions can drag on forever. **Stick to one pointer per declaration** and always initialize variables and the source of confusion disappears.
>
> See The Design and Evolution of C++ for a longer discussion of the C declaration syntax.

Comment: It’s interesting that Stroustrup does not mention there the fact that this “style” fails for arrays and functions. You cannot write `int [3] p;` to declare an array of 3 `int` or `int (char) p` for a function that takes a `char` and returns an `int`. It would have been possible to introduce a new declaration syntax that put a complete description of the type first and then a list of identifiers being declared. Instead, we have this kludge which is ugly due to its contrast with the grammar.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Aren't you mixing up the unrelated things? In pointer declaration, `int *p` and `int* p` both are valid and Bjarne gave a justification as to why `int* p` is preferable in C++ compare to C. It's about placement of `*`. In your comment, you have mentioned _this “style” fails for arrays and functions. You cannot write `int [3] p;` to declare an array of 3 `int`...._, of course, because it's not as per the array declaration syntax of C++ lang. For array declaration, the standards says .... contd..

Comment: (quoting c++11#8.3.4) - Arrays[dcl.array] In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form `D1 [constant-expressionopt]attribute-specifier-seqopt`, `[]` comes after `D1`. If it would have been allowed to place `[]` before `D1` then probably the comparison would have make sense.

Comment: In both `*p` and `p[3]`, `*p` and `p[3]` are *declarators* that are separate from the type in the grammar. In writing `int* p`, Stroustrop abuses the flexibility of spaces in the syntax to group two tokens that are not grouped in the grammar. The fact that this abuse is not possible with arrays and functions shows that it is an ugly kludge.

Answer (score 25):

I cannot speak for Bjarne, but tying the asterisk (and ampersand in case of reference) to the type makes sense because being a pointer is semantically part of the type of the variable. The name of the variable is `p` and its type is `int*`. The name is not `*p` and the type is not `int`.

It is nearly always possible to avoid multiple variable declarations in a single declaration, so that is not an issue.

In my opinion, this approach is clearer, especially in case of return types:

```
T*
function(Args...);

T
*function(Args...);
```

Comment: If you look at the grammar, it is not part of the type. The declaration is divided into parts, and the type and the declarator are in separate parts. The type is `int`, and the declarator is `*p`. The grammar binds `*` to `p` before it binds `*p` to `int`. As K&R explained, `int *p` gives a picture of how `*p` is used: It is an `int`. So `*` is part of the picture of the expression `*p`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am referring to the semantic meaning, not to the grammar. If you use `decltype(p)`, you will not get `int`. I'll add clarification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I recall observing the same when reading the grammatical rules in the K&R second edition.  Galik mentions that Stroustrup's use is a result of his desire for backwards compatibility.  What a mess!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added an image of what I believe you were referring to in K&R.  Perhaps BS believes that grammar changes with C++?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think the philosophy is diferent, as @eerorika said `decltype(p)` will not give you `int`. C++ is strongly typed, what you are saying is more an implication of weak typing like in C.

Comment: @eerorika I think you should add the second reason here that Leon Brands pointed out in his answer.

Comment: @eerorika I suggest to add that part about `decltype` to your answer. Showing that this is how *the language* sees it means a lot.

Comment: Imho, it's a bad idea to split function declarations over several lines like this. With the declarations in the last example, I cannot easily distinguish them from function calls in `grep` output. A function is one thing, and its interface can and should be declared as one. That way, the presence of the return type signals a declaration, the absence of a `;` signals an implementation, and everything else is actually a call. Without the return type, I have to start parsing the arguments to see whether they are a variable declaration or not, and that fails completely when there are no arguments.

Comment: @notaorb: The C and C++ grammars are identical in this aspect.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: This has nothing to do with strong typing versus weak typing. The grammar is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica It's a personal preference, just like the pointer whitespace. I just prefer not having to scroll the screen right, and try to hunt for the function name from something like `explicit constexpr [[nodiscard]] namespace::template_name<template_arguments> name_of_class::name_of_function(Args&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(some_expression)) {`. Trailing return type doesn't solve this entirely since attributes and keywords are still first.

Comment: @eerorika Well, that's what the `--color` option of `grep` is for ;-) But I see your point. Especially C++ can hide the name of the function quite successfully. Still, I'd much rather have that load of waffle spewed out at me than the other extreme, which would only put the function name plus the `(` on a line, with the keywords, return type, argument types, attributes, whatever all on separate lines. In such cases, I have no idea what the function's mention actually does before I've seen the context lines.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Isent what I said another way of saying what you said at first? You basically said C sees this as a way to denote how the variable is used. It is an int that is used to denote a memory address.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: No.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "`int *p` gives a picture of how `*p` is used: It is an `int`" That would mean, `p` is a `int` that stores a memory address, `*` in the declaration denotes this semantic use.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: So? The **conclusion** that `p` is a pointer to an `int` is not the issue. The **structure** of the declaration is the issue. (Also “`p` is an `int` that stores a memory address” is not correct. `p` is a pointer. Some implementations may implement pointers much like they do integers, but they are not integers in C or C++ semantics, and some implement them differently from integers.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your absolutely right in the regard that `p` is not an `int` that stores a memory address. I'm saying that is how it came across (in terms of the semantics of the structure of the declaration), at least how I read it.

Answer (score 10):

I believe stroustrup's style implies that variable declarations like those should be avoided. This also seems to be the general consensus among the community.